# meteor gets stuck on Processing files with ecmascript (for

Tags: meteor

Latest meteor version 1.4.0.1. All of a sudden it got stuck on `Processing files with ecmascript (for...` step. Killing and restarting didn't work, neither did rebooting.

What I tried: `meteor reset`, rebooting, deleting build and cache folders in project's .meteor folder, deleting and reinstalling npm packages. Removing .meteor in my home folder and reinstalling meteor from scratch. Removing packages, both meteor and npm, that I no longer use.

This is something in my project because creating a new meteor project and running it works fine. The project uses React and has a number of components.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by process of elimination. I saved a .js file in my client/js/lib folder while working on a feature. At some point later I accidentally saved my meteor application's home page in the same folder! Guess I was too tired. Found the folder and then saw the html and a subfolder with meteor-generated scripts. Removed them and everything clicked. My exact steps:

- create a new meteor project, copy over `package.json` and
  `.meteor/packages` files run meteor npm install and then run the
  project with meteor
- while the project is running start copying over root app folders one
  by one, wait for app to recompile before moving on to each folder
- my problem surfaced when I copied over the client folder. Meteor said
  refreshing client and got stuck there.
- I removed the client folder, killed the process (run `ps` command, kill
  -9 [PID] where PID is the process id with the high CPU time.) and then restarted meteor again
- created client folder manually and then started copying client/*
  items over one by one
- that's when I noticed the app_name.html and app_name folder with a
  lot of .js files in it!

I removed them and everything works now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try running meteor reset command and then running the project again.

Comment: thank you, I tried that. I'll update the question with what I've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar (but different) problem.  I am trying to use plotly.js with meteor.  I downloaded the plotly.js file and put it into my client/lib directory.  Now, when I try to run meteor, I get the same error being described above.  I thought plotly.js worked with meteor?  If I remove plotly.js (or rename it to a non js file), meteor works fine...so the issue is clearly with plotly.js

Comment: you could try placing plotly.js into your public/js folder and referencing it in your `head` tag. That way meteor won't process it.